Converting polar equation $\theta$ = $\pi$/4 into cartesian form, do I need to specify a domain?
I am trying to convert the polar equation $\theta$ = $\pi$/4 into its cartesian form, and I am aware that the answer is y=x.
However, if I do not specify a domain, i.e. x >= 0, then the line y=x extends to the negative x side, which is actually the polar equation $\theta$=5$\pi$/4.
When I checked online resources, including a similar question in this forum (How to convert $\theta = \pi/3$ into cartesian form?), they do not specify the need to state the domain of x.
Is it not necessary to state the domain for converting? If so, why not?

There is an underlying issue as to whether you think polar equations allow negative $r$, mentioned in the comments to your linked question.  If not, then you have a ray rather than a line.

Ah ok. So it depends on the conventions so to speak. In other words, in my case, where the syllabus tells us to ignore points where r is negative, I have a ray (or a half-line), and I should specify that x >= 0. However, in cases where they allow negative r, then they would not need to specify the domain.

I would not concentrate on $x \ge 0$,  as for a polar equations, any restrictions should be on $r$ and $\theta$.  $x \ge 0$ could be a side effect of saying $r \ge 0$ (which you might or might not want to do) and $-\frac{\pi}2 \le \theta \le \frac{\pi}2$ (which in general seems unreasonably restrictive).

But I am converting the polar equation into a cartesian equation, so shouldn't the restriction for this converted (cartesian) equation be on x and y instead? (i.e. should my final answer for this question be y=x, x>=0, or simply y=x)

If you are told the polar equation is $\theta=\frac \pi 2$ with the restriction $r \ge 0$, then the Cartesian equation is $y=x$ with the restriction $x \ge 0, y \ge 0$.  But $x \ge 0, y \ge 0$ is part of the answer, not the question.  If $r$ can have negative values then so too can $x$ and $y$ in this case. In other cases such as $r=2$ you can have negative $x$ or $y$ in $x^2+y^2=4$ even though $r$ is always positive.
